# CDI error in weblogic 12.1.1

Tags: java, weblogic, java-ee-6, cdi, jboss-weld

I have a CDI bean annotated with @Named and @RequestScoped.
It is working perfectly in Glassfish 3.1.2 but when I deploy it in Weblogic 12.1.1 I get the following error!

> Caused By: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-000075 Normal scoped managed bean implementation class has a public field: 
>   public@Named @RequestScoped class com.x.y.web.monitoring.MyController

I don't have any public field in my bean!!! all of them are private and I use getters and setters.
Is this a bug in weblogic 12.1.1 ?
How can I update weld version in weblogic?

Comment: Are you bundling an AspectJ library?

Comment: No I'm not. When I have CDI interceptors and decorators I don't need Aspectj anymore! ;)

Comment: I was asking, because i recall having some issues with different versions of ASpectJ on my classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly sounds like an issue in WebLogic. I'm pretty sure they're using an old version of Weld, you'll have to ask in the WebLogic forms or contacts about updating, I haven't seen anything about how to update the version.

Comment: Thanks Jason, but was this a bug in weld implementation in past? like glassfish weblogic uses OSGi bundles and i tried replacing the bundle with newer version that I got from jboss repository, but it did not work and gave me another error! I think weblogic has it's own mechanism for making OSGi bundles from a jar file.

Comment: Certainly sounds like an issue in WebLogic! ;)

Comment: I not surprised anymore, I encountered more bugs in Weblogic JEE implementations, which nobody cared about (i didn't paid). So I stopped caring as well and moved to better platform

Answer (score 0):

Some IDEs (like Netbeans) import wrong class for `viewscope` automatically. Be sure you imported  `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped` not `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped`.